# Qt application exit automatically when mainWindow is hidden

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new to Qt. I'm having a strange problem. When I hide my mainWindow(which opens when the application starts) my application closes after sometime automatically. But if I don't use this->hide() application works fine.

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "aclogin.h"
#include "atm.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_bank_clicked();
    void on_pushButton_atm_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    aclogin *_login;
    atm *_atmEnter;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint | Qt::WindowMaximizeButtonHint | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_bank_clicked()
{
    this->hide();
    _login = new aclogin(this);
    _login->setWindowTitle("Log In");
    _login->setModal(true);
    _login->show();
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_atm_clicked()
{
    this->hide();
    _atmEnter = new atm(this);
    _atmEnter->setWindowTitle("ATM");
    _atmEnter->setModal(true);
    _atmEnter->show();
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow *_BankSystem = new MainWindow();
    _BankSystem->setWindowTitle("Bank System");
    _BankSystem->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

But application works fine if I hide other windows.
Thanks.

stripped down the code, and added a .ui file. The behavior indicated by the OP is correct. Upon execution of the hide() method:

the main window indeed does hide
the app disappears from the dock
the app disappears from Task Manager
(Interestingly enough, from Creator's perspective, the app has not exited. If I click the run button, it gives me the "waiting for applications to stop" message.)

/* mainwindow.h */

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
private slots:
    void on_pushButton_bank_clicked();
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

/* mainwindow.c */

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}


MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_bank_clicked()
{
    this->hide();
}
```

/* main.c */

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "widget.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow *_BankSystem = new MainWindow();

    _BankSystem->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

And here's the .ui file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Widget</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Widget">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="atm">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>80</x>
     <y>30</y>
     <width>80</width>
     <height>18</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>atm</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="bank">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>230</x>
     <y>30</y>
     <width>80</width>
     <height>18</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>bank</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: This is not normal or expected. I have not seen this behavior in the 11 years that I have used Qt at work.

Comment: Your code is incomplete, it seems to need `"ui_mainwindow.h"`.  Please reduce it to a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem; thanks.

Comment: The code example is fine. In 5 minutes I was able to create my own ui file, and replicate his problem. Anyone with Qt designer knowledge could do the same, and those without this knowledge probably shouldn't try to answer this question.

Comment: A complete example is a requirement of a the site. The link in the second comment explains that.

Comment: OK, maybe the code example isn't "fine," but given that I was able to reproduce his problem (and confirm that QWidget exhibits the same behavior), it seems a legitimate problem and one worth solving. It would be a shame if it were closed, and we couldn't get more people looking at it. IMO of course.

Answer (score 2):

[QGuiApplication](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html)

quitOnLastWindowClosed : bool
This property holds whether the application implicitly quits when the last window is closed.

The default is true.

If this property is true, the applications quits when the last visible primary window (i.e. window with no parent) is closed.

Access functions:

```
bool    quitOnLastWindowClosed()
void    setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(bool quit)
```

Also you have a memory leak at `MainWindow *_BankSystem = new MainWindow();`. You can solve that by adding a parent to `new MainWindow()`, delete or smart pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `QApplication::setQuitOnLastWindowClosed` as `a.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false)` to prevent the application to terminate if the last window was closed.

Comment: Not sure this is the issue. The question is about hiding MainWindow not closing it.

Comment: a.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false)  will not reopen app.